# Get post ids sorted by meta_key

Tags: custom-field, query

I have defined a `post_view_count` meta_key to store the number of post views.
I would like to get an array of post ids sorted by `post_view_count` value to use in the 
`functions.php` file.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's easy. :) You would use [get_posts](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts) function. See [WP_Query class](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Parameters) for complete list of parameters that you can use.

```
function get_posts_by_view_count() {
$ids = array();

$args = array(
    'orderby'   =>  'meta_value_num',
    'order'     =>  'DESC',
    'meta_key'  =>  'post_view_count'
);  
$posts = get_posts( $args );

if( $posts ) {
    foreach( $posts as $post ) {
        $ids[] = $post->ID;
    }
}

return $ids;
}
```

Comment: is there a way to make this more efficient? Ie return only the IDs as get_posts will actually return everything (wasting resources?). I've looked at get_column but that uses actual SQL which i'd rather avoid.